# The following label is truncated?? . Any suggestion how to display MultiLine UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, swift4

`UILabel` does not wrap and shows more than one line.
According to the docs, my text should wrap on word boundary and be displayed in 2 lines. However, this does not occur. I'm using `Swift 4` and the latest version of `XCode`.

```
    let instruction = UILabel()
    instruction.text = "Click And Touch Number To Make A  Choice"
    instruction.backgroundColor = .white
    instruction.textColor = .black
    instruction.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    instruction.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    instruction.textAlignment = .left
    instruction.numberOfLines = 0
    instruction.sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 1):

The label to wrap should have a frame whether with frame layout by setting width value or by auto layout by setting leading and trailing constraints that makes the label know it's boundaries and wrap when hitting the right most boundary to another line and so on according to it's content

```
    let instruction = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    instruction.text = "Click And Touch Number To Make A  Choice"
    instruction.backgroundColor = .white
    instruction.textColor = .black
    instruction.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    instruction.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    instruction.textAlignment = .left
    instruction.numberOfLines = 0
    instruction.sizeToFit()
    self.view.addSubview(instruction)
    instruction.center = self.view.center
```

[image]

Comment: I make the following in viewWillAppear (later in the code) ..   bar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height * 6 / 7, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height / 7).     instruction.frame = CGRect(x:0 , y: 5 , width: self.bounds.width * 2 / 3, height: 20)      bar.addSubview(instruction) And I am getting the label a place but truncated..

Comment: set width and height as you like , the idea is that u must specify a valid non-zero frame

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs:

> **In some cases**, if a view does not have a superview, it may size itself to the screen bounds.

But in your case it doesn't. You just need to constrain label's width somehow and `sizeToFit()` wouldn't be even needed (Auto Layout will do its job) e.g.

```
instruction.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
instruction.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
```